# What control is Apple using here? (screenshot included) UIButton? UITableViewCell? Something else?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface

This is a really stupid but very simple question. I know it is. Please don't tell me that I should have googled first. I did, a lot. I just need someone to point me in the right direction and I can take it from there. Ok, with that out of the way...

What control is Apple using in its Settings, Contacts and Calendar app that looks like a Round Rect button (and you can click on it), but has text aligned to the left (but not all the way to the left; there is a margin) and text aligned to the right at the same time? In most cases it also has a little arrow (or greather than symbol) on the right side, signifying that it will slide in another ViewController from the right when you click it. Is it a UIBUtton? A clickable UITableViewCell? (If so, what is the UITableViewCell hosted in?) It's so ubiquitous in Apple's built-in apps that I'm really astounded that I can't find an example of how to reproduce it. I'm trying to not re-invent the wheel here; there must be some tutorial/example out there that I just haven't been able to find. Or maybe it's a separate control that's right there in XCode and I'm just overlooking it. A link with a very brief conceptual overview would be greatly appreciated.

[image: A screenshot with several examples.]

Comment: It's a table view. For some reason they decided to use table views as button/label groups everywhere in iOS.

Comment: Seems so simple now that I don't know how I overlooked it. I just wasn't using the right search terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I am pretty sure it's a table view set to grouped. Check out the following related stack-overflow question:

[How to create a iPhone Settings-like view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935584/how-to-create-a-iphone-settings-like-view)

The main thing to do is setting the table to grouped by the looks of things.

Comment: That was the key that I was missing: Setting the table view to grouped. I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

It is a grouped `UITableView`. You can see a description of this table style in the following Apple page: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH3-SW1

Comment: Thanks for this link. The UITableViewCell style that I'm looking for is called UITableViewCellStyleValue1. Excellent.

Answer (score 2):

These are **UITableViewCells** of a **Grouped Tableview** that have been customized as per the need. There are some sample codes available for making similar cells as used in iPhone settings :

1. [InAppSettings](https://github.com/kgn/InAppSettings)
2. [InAppSettingsKit](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: It's not a "section based table". Both grouped and plain style tables can have multiple sections. A more correct description would be "a multi-sectioned, grouped-styled table view".